# When trying to open python executable script file (myfile.exe) , getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot.preprocessors'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I created a chat bot using chatter bot and GUI of bot using tkinter. When I train my bot, it creates a sqlite3 db in same folder where my python script present. Also I have data files in yml format through which my bot gets trained. I am using python 3.6.

Able to converted my python script to exe using pyinstaller. Below command I ran:

```
pyinstaller --noupx --onefile ChatBotGUI.py
```

When I ran ChatBotGUI.exe under dist folder, gets below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ChatBotGUI.py", line 77, in <module>
  File "ChatBotGUI.py", line 22, in __init__
  File "chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 69, in __init__
  File "chatterbot\utils.py", line 15, in import_module
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot.preprocessors'
[17728] Failed to execute script ChatBotGUI
```

Not able to fix this issue. Much needed help require :) to fix this issue.

Note: When I ran ChatBotGUI.cpython-36.pyc from **pycache** , it ran flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solution is right in the last error message. ! 
Wherever you have written `from chatterbot import ChatBot` , you need to add another line `from chatterbot import preprocessors` ,

Alternatively, you can import everything by writing `from chatterbot import *`

Hope this solves the issue !!